# Transform Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the problem
\begin{align}
\min\limits_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} J(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad e(x)=0, \ g(x)\leq0.
\end{align}
Reformulate this problem into a problem with equality- and box constraints.

By box constraints there are just simple bounds meant, i.e.
\begin{align}
x\in \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_a\leq x\leq x_b \ \text{componentwise in } \mathbb{R}^n\}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a slack variable $s$ and write

$$
\min_{x,s} J(x) \quad \text{s.t.} \quad e(x) = 0,\; g(x) + s = 0
$$

with the box constraint $s \geq 0$.